# How to use a variable as pdf name in mPDF?

Tags: php, variables, mpdf

I have a page that generates a pdf by using mPDF. 
The name of the pdf is made by this code

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','D');
```

But i need the name to be a combination of the 2 varables $counter and $main_product so the name of the pdf is somthing like 1648-2-part-door.pdf

Any way to make this possible with mPDF?

Comment: $mpdf->Output($counter . '-' . $main_product . '.pdf', 'D');

Comment: Your anser works perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$counter = 3;
$main_product ='white-door';

$mpdf->Output("{$counter}-{$main_product}.pdf",'D');
```

**Later edit in order to answer the comment:**
I recommend the use of {$variable} inside " " tags because is way simpler. For example you can write:

```
"Your name is $name."
```

instead of

```
'Your name is '.$name.'.';
```

When you add { } inside "" tags you can also use n-dimensional arrays without a problem. Example:

```
"Your name is {$person['id_properties']['name']}."
```

P.S. Note! This only works in double quote tags (" ") not in simple ones(' ').

Comment: That also works. - but how is that diffrent than the answer adiebler gave? :)

Comment: @KristianTarp Hey. I reedited my original answer in order to show you the difference.